# How I can force HTTPS links on my website?

Tags: php, https

I'm trying to force all links on my website to be https instead of http.
I have tried by redirect the domain from my web-host control panel to https, but it's still the same.
Each time I enter the website the page become http.

I search around and I found this tiny code inside my config file.

```
// server url and base path, usually you don't need to change this
                'base_url' => (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http').'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),
                'base_path' => getcwd(),
```

**Is this responsible for this issue! if yes! what should I change to make it https?**

Answer (score 0):

you can use htaccess to do this:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Where I should put this file exactly? inside the main root?

Comment: yes you need to create file named .htaccess at site root  and put the code there.

Comment: When I do that the whole website shuting off, it doesnt work!

Comment: RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to redirect all **HTTP** address to **HTTPS** is by using a **.htaccess** file.

Create a file named **.htaccess** in your root directory if you don't have any. then copy this in to the file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: To be sure, I just need to edit "yourdomain.com" and leave  "/$1 [R,L]" after the domain right?

Comment: I did the same, I used this RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L=301] now it's open the link correctly but there is no website "error the page doesnt redirected correclty"